# Can't delete rows with specyfic conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have (again) a probelm with data frame processing in pandas.

Four columns: `Name`, `Sample`, `A1_TOP`, `A2_TOP`.

Sometimes in `A1_TOP` or `A2_TOP` i have a gaps. Gaps are a symbols '-' or '0'. 
I wrote a line of code to deleting rows contains gaps form table.

a = my Data frame.

My code:

```
a = a.loc[(a['A1_TOP'] != '-') | (a['A2_TOP'] != '-')]
a = a.loc[(a['A1_TOP'] != '0') | (a['A2_TOP'] != '0')]
```

But when I run it, I got no errors. Result is dataframe still conatins gaps. Yesterday I had another files to processing and that part of code works fine. Today no.

For example I have a gap in first row in data frame:

```
Name Sample A1_TOP A2_TOP
Adam  Smith   -     B
```

And that row shoud be deleted. But it isn't. `type(df['A1_TOP][0]) = str` so it's not a problem with type.

Can someone tell me what is  wrong with this code?

EDIT:
If I split command like that:

```
a = a.loc[a['A1_TOP'] != '-']
a = a.loc[a['A2_TOP'] != '-']
```

It works... but why first way not?

Comment: you have white space in it ? so it may be ` - ` not '-'

Comment: Thanks for answer but no :( `a['A1_TOP'][1] = '-'` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it be `&`?

```
a = a.loc[(a['A1_TOP'] != '-') & (a['A2_TOP'] != '-')]
```

Comment: Ouh... it's work. But why? It's not "AND"? 
It should not be so, that it will run only if there will be a gap in both columns?

Comment: @Artur yes or mean either of them meet the condition it will return the True